# How to read the latest file in sas mainframes

Tags: sas, mainframe

I have a bunch of files like :

```
EESE.ABC123.ECIM.SAS.D160128,
EESE.ABC123.ECIM.SAS.D160202,
EESE.ABC123.ECIM.SAS.D160328,
EESE.ABC123.ECIM.SAS.D160502
```

I only want to read the latest created (D160502) file in mainframes using sas. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you only want to read one particular data set, why mention the other three at all? How does that come about?

Answer (score -1):

If you can use JCL then the following statement :

abc123 DD DSN=EESE.ABC123.ECIM.SAS(0), DISP=SHR

then in SAS use infile statement:

infile abc123 ;

it will take latest file. Hope this helps

** I don't know whether you are using JCL or not, so posted with JCL in case it might help you.

Comment: Thanks Bharath, I am using JCL but its not a generation file, i tried the way you explained but it did not work. Any other suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Those datasets are not GDGs, so (0) won't work. However, if appropriate , you might like to make EESE.ABC123.ECIM.SAS a GDG as it could make processing these files easier.